# Combine hash and non-hash URLs in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, shebang

Is there some way how to combine **hash** and **non-hash** URLs in Backbone.js application?

I set `Backbone.history.start({pushState: true})`. When user click on some link, I fetch JSON data from server, update page, and call `Backbone.history.navigate` to change URL in browser from (for example from `example.com/zlinsky/kampan/mf/` to `example.com/moravskoslezsky/kampan/mf/`).
If user copy URL from browser and open in second tab, he will see same page (so every page updated this way have corresponding page on server). This is exactly what I want.

But now I have problem...

I have several `<select>` on page too. When user change value in them, I make some dynamic changes on page (without fetching JSON from server, updates is done only on client side). I would like change URLs according to `<select>`, for example to `example.com/moravskoslezsky/kampan/mf/#state1` (so, when somebody send this URL, the other side will see same page, in same state as sender).

I could not find way, how to do it in Backbone.js. If I set `pushState: true` on `Backbone.history`, `Router` ignore hash tags.
If I set `pushState: false`, I am not able to set URLs like I describe in first paragraph above.

Thank you for any hint.

Comment: were you able to solve the issue? i'm facing exactly the same problem. when pushState is true, i'm not able route urls containing hash part; hash is just completely ignored.

Answer (score 2):

You can call:
    `Backbone.history.navigate( "/foo/bar#fragment" )`

But i don't think it's a good idea, because ie doesn't support pushstate, so backbone is going to use hash bang urls (in ie).

Maybe you could use querystrings: `Backbone.history.navigate( "/foo/bar?foo=bar", true )` which will be in modern browsers: `http://domain.tld/foo/bar?foo=bar` and in ie: `http://domain.tld#/foo/bar?foo=bar`